# Question with Predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have the question: "Translate the following argument into the language of predicate
logic. Determine if it is valid or invalid. Justify your answer by providing
either an interpretation or a proof.
All babies are illogical and nothing that is despised can manage
a crocodile. Not all illogical things are despised, therefore some
baby can manage some crocodile."

I have it translated in a way that I think is correct with
$$(∀x~(Bx → Ix) ∧ ∀y~(Mc → ¬Dy)) , \\(∃x~(Ix → Dx))\\
\therefore~(∃x~(Bx → Mc))$$

I am trying to go through with a proof and I have not solved it, I keep on getting stuck while attempting it. Any help with forming a proof or an interpretation that proves it's validity would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your "translation" would be easier to follow if you explained what the predicate symbols stand for.

Answer (score 0):

You want the second to say "There is an illogical thing and it is not despised."

Also the third should likewise say "There is a baby and it can manage crocodiles."

Remember, existential are restricted by a conjunction.  Universals are restricted by a conditional.